# How to make TensorFlow use 100% of GPU?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, gpu, nvidia

I have a laptop that has an RTX 2060 GPU and I am using Keras and TF 2 to train an LSTM on it. I am also monitoring the gpu use by `nvidia-smi` and I noticed that the jupyter notebook and TF are using maximum 35% and usually the gpu is being used between 10-25%.

With current conditions, it took more than 7 hours to train this model, I want to know if I am doing something wrong or it is a limitation of Keras and TF?

My nvidia-smi output:

```
Sun Nov  3 00:07:37 2019       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 430.26       Driver Version: 430.26       CUDA Version: 10.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce RTX 2060    Off  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| N/A   51C    P3    22W /  N/A |    834MiB /  5931MiB |     24%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1032      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           330MiB |
|    0      1251      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                         333MiB |
|    0      1758      G   ...equest-channel-token=622209288718607755   121MiB |
|    0      5086      G   ...uest-channel-token=12207632792533837012    47MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

My LSTM:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dropout

regressor = Sequential()

regressor.add(LSTM(units = 180, return_sequences = True, input_shape = (X_train.shape[1], 3)))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

regressor.add(LSTM(units = 180, return_sequences = True))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

regressor.add(LSTM(units = 180, return_sequences = True))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

regressor.add(LSTM(units = 180, return_sequences = True))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

regressor.add(LSTM(units = 180, return_sequences = True))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

regressor.add(LSTM(units = 180))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

regressor.add(Dense(units = 1))

regressor.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mean_squared_error')

regressor.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = 10, batch_size = 32, callbacks=[cp_callback])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TensorFlow automatically takes care of optimizing GPU resource allocation via CUDA & cuDNN, assuming latter's properly installed. The usage statistics you're seeing are mainly that of memory/compute resource 'activity', not necessarily utility (execution); see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40937894/nvidia-smi-volatile-gpu-utilization-explanation). That your utility is "only" 25% is a good thing - otherwise, if you substantially increased your model size (which isn't large as-is), you'd OOM.

To increase usage, increase batch size, model size, or whatever would increase the *parallelism* of computations; note that making the model deeper would increase GPU's memory utility, but far less so its compute-utility.

Also, consider using `CuDNNLSTM` instead of `LSTM`, which can run **10x faster** and use *less* GPU memory (courtesy of algorithmic artisanship), but more compute-utility. Lastly, inserting `Conv1D` as the first layer with `strides > 1` will significantly increase train speed by reducing input size, without necessarily harming performance (it can in fact improve it).

---

**Update**: overclocking the GPU is an option, but I'd advise against it as it can wear out the GPU in the long run (and all DL is "long run"). There's also "over-volting" and other hardware tweaks, but all should be used for some short applications. What'll make the greatest difference is your [input data pipeline](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data_performance).

Answer (score 0):

Try setting memory_limit when initializing a logical device.
In my case I have an RTX 3060 6GB and I had the same problem with `tensorflow==2.9.1`, so this worked:

```py
gpus = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
if gpus: 
    tf.config.set_logical_device_configuration(
        gpus[0],
        [tf.config.LogicalDeviceConfiguration(memory_limit=5292)]
    )

logical_gpus = tf.config.list_logical_devices('GPU')
print(len(gpus), "Physical GPU,", len(logical_gpus), "Logical GPUs")
```

Here is before setting memory_limit:

[image: Screenshot from 2022-08-12 16-26-25]

> `nvidia-smi` output
>
> [image: Screenshot from 2022-08-12 16-36-28]

and after setting memry_limit to `5292MiB`:

[image: Screenshot from 2022-08-12 16-25-38]

> `nvidia-smi` output
>
> [image: Screenshot from 2022-08-12 16-37-25]

The difference of memory between Tensorflow report and nvidia-smi probably has to do with other initialization that tensorflow has to do.

If you try to set memory limit to a value close to your VRAM size (in my case is `6144MiB`) you will get an `InternalError: Graph execution error` when you run `model.fit()` later, for me I could set memory_limit to `5844` leaving only 300~MiB for other processes and my model trains with no error.

Answer (score -2):

There's no limitations of GPU usage in tensorflow or jupyter. The problem is that you can't load your GPU. Usually this means that you data loader works slower than GPU processes the data. Try to profile your workflow and you'll find a bottleneck.

Comment: False information; GPU isn't limitless, and any resource (model/data) _can_ be loaded onto the GPU. On 'data loader', however, it's true that input data processing time can be longer than GPU train time.